# Spring needs a server restart to refresh domain objects

Tags: java, wordpress, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

guys:

I've been fighting all morning in order to find what's the problem with my spring controller, which were not working properly while getting into the database and refreshing a table depending on the data within such ddbb.

I have a separate project for all of my business logic, which I export as a JAR, and include it into the lib folder (and classpath) of my web spring MVC app.
And I have a controller for such an UploadCalendar.jsp, from which I instantiate a domain service (external jar) which in theory gets into the database, grabs all of the information on days and turns (busy and available), and then paints a calendar (table) to upload to a wordpress site.
The jsp only runs the business logic of the process, throughout the external service class.

Since If I run the uploadCalendar method from outside the Web App, it runs perfectly, I get a lot confused why running the exact same method from within the Spring controller, it doesn't update the calendar.

I have to say that with my service class, I get into the database, and loads into memory all data needed to perform the getCalendar() String method. Then, I create a file, and upload that file to the remote server.

I don't know if it's Spring that is avoiding to reload the data, even when the data is changed into the ddbb?

My Controller code is like this:

```
@Autowired
FileService fileService;

@Autowired
MainService main;

@RequestMapping(path="/uploadCalendar", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView UploadCalendar() throws IOException, DDBBException{
    //This, in theory, should get into the ddbb, and load all needed data
    main.loadAllTurns();

    //Runs getCalendar, takes the calendar string, and writes a local file
    fileService.WriteFile(main.getCalendarTableString(), conf.getCalendarFile2UploadURI());

    //Upload the file
    fileService.UploadFileFTP(conf.getCalendarFile2UploadURI(), conf.getCalendarRemoteFileURI());

    return new ModelAndView("/web/UploadCalendar.jsp");
}
```

I have been making a lot of debug, just to find that it wasn't a code error, but just anyhow of some cache-problem with the web app, because if I restart the server, then the calendar is correctly updated, the file is correctly updated, and everything is ok.
But if I just get into the database once again, and change a row, I also need a new restart of the server for the calendar string to be updated.

Do you have any idea on what the problem could be related to?

Comment: Also: If I hit "refresh" on eclipse for the project... tomcat reloads... and it also  updates the calendar... So it's not only restarting the server, but refreshing the eclipse project (which at the end, pushes tomcat to reload).

Comment: Also, If I deploy the Web app onto another tomcat server, I have the same problem: I need the tomcat to be restarted to update the file with the ddbb changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found what was the problem about. I write it down just in case somebody could have been experiencing the same problem:

I was saving the data from the ddbb into a global attribute of the Service class. And getCalendarTableString() was not calling the ddbb to update the data into the attribute. 
Every single time I executed the "algorithm" from within a console scenario, Java was creating and instantiating the service class from the ground up, so every time, the getCalendarTableString method was getting a fresh snapshot of the ddbb.
But when calling from the web app, if I change a row in the ddbb after letting tomcat to instantiate the class, since getCalendar was believing the data should be there into the global attribute and was not calling the ddbb once again, it was taking old data.

However... I don't know why it failed when I just added loadAllTurns() to the GET method on the controller...

Anyhow, it now works.

Regards